# Get push notification of other App then run code with string of push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I'm currently trying to run a code after another app sends a push notification.
Is there a trigger for something like that. I don't need to let the App run in Background.
Also the App doesn't need to get published in the Store.

for example:
App A = Messenger App
App B = the one i try to programm

App A sends a push notification like "David sent 'Our Network is currently offline. We try to fix it as soon as possible'"

App B then executes a code with the Text of the Push Notification in a string.

i'm thankful for every help i can get.

Comment: You'll not be able to read the notifications for another app. It is just not possible in iOS due to the way that apps are sandboxed

Comment: would it be possible to do this via android?

Comment: I don’t think you can do that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> App A sends a push notification like "David sent 'Our Network is
> currently offline. We try to fix it as soon as possible'"
>
> App B then executes a code with the Text of the Push Notification in a
> string.

That is POSSIBLE! Given that the App **A and B** both receive the same remote push notifications.

You can choose to not present the push notification inside **App B.** through the use of `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate

And again with that protocol, you can extract the string or whatever data you need from the remote push notification upon receiving it and then present it to the user or don't at all.